# Prove there is $\xi\in (0,\lambda)$ s.t. $\int\limits_0^{\lambda}\frac{x^n}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\xi^n\frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

> Let $\lambda>0$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that there is
> $\xi\in (0,\lambda)$ such that:

> $$\int\limits_0^{\lambda}\frac{x^n}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\xi^n\frac{\pi}{4}.$$

**Attempt**. Using mean value theorem for integrals would give us some
$\xi\in (0,\lambda)$ such that:

$$\int\limits_0^{\lambda}\frac{x^n}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\xi^n \int\limits_0^{\lambda}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x =\xi^n\arctan\lambda,$$
which is not our case. I guess there is some kind of adjustment needed.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

**Partial answer**

If $0 \lt \lambda \lt 1$ then

$$0 \le \int\limits_0^{\lambda}\frac{x^n}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x \le \lambda^n \frac{\pi}{4}$$ and as $x \mapsto x^n$ is increasing, we can thind $\xi \in (0,\lambda)$ such that
$$\int\limits_0^{\lambda}\frac{x^n}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\xi^n\frac{\pi}{4}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\lambda > 0$. By mean value theorem $\int_0^{\lambda} \frac{x^n}{1+x^2} \mathrm{d}x = \xi^{n-1} \int_0^{\lambda} \frac{x}{1+x^2} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\xi^{n-1}}{2}\log(\lambda^2 + 1)$, where $\xi \in (0,\lambda]$. Note that $\log(\lambda^2+1) < \frac{\pi}{2}\lambda$ for all $\lambda > 0$. So, $0 < \int_0^{\lambda} \frac{x^n}{1+x^2} \mathrm{d}x < \frac{\pi}{4}\lambda^n$. By intermediate value theorem there must be some $\xi \in (0,\lambda)$ with $ \int_0^{\lambda} \frac{x^n}{1+x^2} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi}{4}\xi^n$.